# Дважды count в mysql запросе

Tags: mysql

Помогите, пожалуйста, с запросом. В таблице есть записи с определенным флагом и без него. Можно ли одним запросом выбрать количество записей с флагом и количество записей без него (или количество записей в таблице)?
Для примера: нужно выбрать кол-во записей с четными id и кол-во записей с нечетными id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    SUM( IF(field_flag, 1, 0) ) AS flag_exist,
    SUM( IF(field_flag, 0, 1) ) AS flag_not_exist
FROM table
```

Comment: То, что надо, спасибо)

Comment: Пожалуйста

Answer (score 3):

[`COUNT(expr)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count)

> Returns a count of the number of **non-NULL values** of expr in the rows retrieved by a SELECT statement. The result is a BIGINT value.

[`NULLIF(expr1, expr2)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_nullif)

> Returns NULL if expr1 = expr2 is true, otherwise returns expr1. This is the same as CASE WHEN expr1 = expr2 THEN NULL ELSE expr1 END.

Соответственно, запрос с выборкой количества четных и нечетных id:

```
SELECT COUNT(NULLIF(id % 2, 1)) AS odd, COUNT(NULLIF(id % 2, 0)) AS even FROM table
```

Проверка:

```
mysql> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test (id integer);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO test VALUES (1), (3), (5), (7), (9), (10), (12);
Query OK, 7 rows affected (0.03 sec)
Records: 7  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT COUNT(NULLIF(id % 2, 1)) AS odd, COUNT(NULLIF(id % 2, 0)) AS even FROM test;
+-----+------+
| odd | even |
+-----+------+
|   2 |    5 |
+-----+------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

Comment: Как я понимаю, этот запрос не вернёт количества, а вернёт много строк с нулями и единицами, которые ещё надо просуммировать.

Comment: Нет, это запрос вернет именно количество одной строкой. Count() - это агрегирующая функция, соответственно если не указан group by, то агрегирование будет по всем строкам. Только в данном случае агрегирование идет не по полю, а по выражению.

Answer (score 1):

Может не лучший пример, но попробуйте так

```
select (select count(id) from table where id%2 = 0) as 'Четные', (select count(id) from table where id%2 > 0) as 'Нечетные'
```

И другой вариант

```
select count(id) from table where id%2 = 0
union all
select count(id) from table where id%2 > 0
```

Во втором варианте будет в две строчки.